# mod_rewrite preventing correct filetype icons from showing on mod_autoindex

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, mod-autoindex

I seem to have a problem which I've been struggling to solve. I'd love a bit of help here.
I have a dump site where I am using `mod_autoindex` and `FancyIndexing`.

I have my `FancyIndexing` icons defined in my `.htaccess` file. I also use `mod_rewrite` to pass the files through several php scripts (depending on the file extension).

Everything works great, except when a file extension is matched on a `RewriteRule`, Apache displays only it's default icon, and not the one specified.

All `FancyIndexing` resources are on the `/imgindex` directory, and all viewers are on the `/viewers` directory.

This is the relevant part of the `.htaccess` file (I'm currently tweaking it, so it's not optimized):

```
Options +Indexes
IndexOptions +XHTML +HTMLTable +FancyIndexing +FoldersFirst +SuppressHTMLPreamble +IconsAreLinks +IgnoreCase +NameWidth=*
IndexIgnore *~ imgindex viewers favicon.ico
HeaderName /imgindex/header.html
ReadmeName /imgindex/footer.html

# ------ Fancy Indexing ----------
AddIcon /imgindex/image.png .jpg .jp2 .jif .jpeg .tiff .tif .pict .pct .bmp .gif .png .psd .tga .ai .indd .fh* .fh10 .xcf .svg
AddIcon /imgindex/app.png .app
AddIcon /imgindex/movie.png .mov .mpg .mpeg .m2v .avi .divx .xvid .swf .wmv .wma .wm* .ram .rm .ogm .ogv
AddIcon /imgindex/txt.png .txt .text .log
# etc, etc.
DefaultIcon /imgindex/text.png

# ------ Rewriting --------
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^viewers/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^imgindex/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*).(css|cs|cpp|h|hpp|pas|xml|js|asm|inc|as|sh|bat|cmd|html)$ /viewers/view_source.php?file=$1.$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^viewers/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^imgindex/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*).(jpg)$ /viewers/viewjpg.php?file=$1.$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]

# (etc, etc.)
```

As I said, everything seems to work great, except for the icons. In the case above, all `.css, .cs, .cpp`, (etc), and all `.jpg` files will use the icon defined in `DefaultIcon`, instead of the one for its filetype (defined in `AddIcon`).

If I remove the `RewriteRule` that matches that filetype, the correct icon gets displayed.

Is this normal, expected behaviour? Any way to override it, if so?

Regards,

Comment: Adding to the "mistery" (or to whatever I'm doing wrong), I tried to add a description to one of the files (i.e. AddDescription "whatever" filename), and it doesn't show either IF it's matched on the RewriteRule. Works perfectly otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems I found out why. mod_rewrite is, for some reason (a bug?) remapping all apr_read_dir() calls, which mod_autoindex uses (I ended up looking at mod_autoindex source code). Since it's considered a subrequest on the mapper module, as a workaround I just added a:

```
RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} false
```

To each of the RewriteRules and it magically worked. Of course, this is just a workaround, since if you actually need a rewriterule on a subrequest, this might not work for you.

I do believe this to be a bug on mod_autoindex, since there's absolutely no reason the filename for the icon and/or description should be ANY different than the one used to actually print the output data.

There could be some obscure reasons to it though.